# Return False if specific string is not in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file

I have this function with looks for a specific string in a text file:

```
def check_for_string(string, file):
   with open(file) as target_file:
      for index, line in enumerate(target_file):
         if string in line:
            return True
            break
```

And it stops when it finds the specific string and returns True.
How can I do it, so it returns True when it found the string and returns False if it did not found the string?

Comment: Add a variable to your code, to track if string is found, on finding, set it to true, but continue the loop. After end of loop, return the flag variable.

Comment: Of course initialise the flag as False before the loop.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Makes no sense to continue if you already found the string.

Comment: @JuanR right, just keep track of the fact that it is found, but can exit the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return `False`:

```
def check_for_string(string, file):
   with open(file) as target_file:
      for index, line in enumerate(target_file):
         if string in line:
            return True
    return False
```

Note: You don't need to put `break` after `return`, it's useless.